# Return an array between start A and B

Tags: ruby

```
$array = []
def range(start_position,end_position)
  for i in start_position..end_position
    $array.push(i)
    puts $array
  end 
  return $array
end 

range(1,10)
```

I was wondering why exactly my array isnt returning. Clearly when I do puts $array, 1-10 is being inserted, but when I call my function I want the array to be returned. Any thoughts, I'm reading through documentation but can't find what i've done wrong or if I have made any syntax errors.

Comment: Oh, I was simply testing whether the numbers were being put into the array, since they werent displaying at all when I called the function. simply for debugging purposes

Comment: You should avoid global variables (i.e. use `foo` not `$foo$).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is essentially correct you just need to omit the `puts $array` within your `for` block. And also no need for the optional `return` keyword. So fixing your code we would have:

```
$array = []
def range(start_position,end_position)
  for i in start_position..end_position
    $array.push(i)
  end 
  $array
end 

p range(1,10) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

[`Kernel#p`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p) performs the [`Kernel#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect) method which as stated in the documentation provides a *human-readable representation* of the object in question. In Ruby it would be much better to do something like this perhaps:

```
def range(start_position,end_position)
  (start_position..end_position).map {|i| i }
end 

p range(1,10) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: great that works. May I know what is wrong with my code, and what p array means?

Comment: A bit confused on the usage of map here. On documentation it says if arr = [1,2,3,4,5], arr.map{|i| i}, makes a new array with 1,2,3,4,5 in it correct?. If so dont we have to put this in a variable. What are you returning in that statement? I come from languages where you need to return, so its a bit weird as to what you are returning.

Comment: oh never mind I see what you did. Thanks. cool solution, definitely much better

Comment: No worries, just so you know in Ruby if we call a method then the _last_ line of code is always the return value of that method.

Comment: It can't hurt to return something though in long pieces of code though can it?

Comment: yes often the use of `return` does help with code readability and many do use it as such.

Answer (score 0):

It returns an array, but you are not doing anything with it, so it is discarded. You could print it (with `p range(1,10)` or `puts range(1,10)` ) or assign it to a variable for later use ( `result = range(1,10)` ). Which is the same as `result = (1..10).to_a`, not using your method at all.

Comment: it worked when I did puts range(1,10), but its simply outputting 1 then next line 2 all the way to 10 on a seperate line. How can I make it output an actual array like [1,2,3,..10]?

Comment: _puts_ is used to display something to end users; _p_ is more for displaying stuff to programmers. Use _p  range(1,10)_.

Comment: hmm, ive read a bit online. Can I deduce that p, will basically print the full array of an specific value?

Comment: Great, thanks. Just started learning ruby this morning and its so much for friendly than js and c++ :o

Comment: Actually, since you declared `$array` outside your method (which is horrible), it _is_ available; just add `p $array` to your code.

Comment: Anything in particular wrong with declaring global variables? Secuirty issues I presume, or bad form?

Comment: If your program grows over time, which simple but effective scripts tend to do, you, or another programmer is likely to need a variable name for an array for which the content is not fixed yet. The likely variable name would be ` $array` , trampling over the original $array in ways your range-method cannot handle.

Answer (score 0):

Your array does return, but you don't do anything with the return value. Try saving it to a variable or print the result:

```
print range(1, 3) # => [1, 2, 3]
```

If you're looking for a simpler way to implement this function, you could use Ruby ranges to do it, something like:

```
def range (start_position, end_position)
    # Create a range and convert it to an array
    # We can omit return
    (start_position .. end_position).to_a
end

print range(1, 3) # => [1, 2, 3]
```

Also beware your function will only work the first time, because you're using a global variable as your starting point. Check what happens when you call it multiple times:

```
print range(1, 3) # => [1, 2, 3]
print range(1, 3) # => [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: cool. Thanks for that. Looks like ruby has alot of built in functions I can use